# configurar la librería phpword en codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpword

Esta es la parte del controlador, en el cual llamo la librería he intento generar el archivo de word, pero no lo he logrado.Ayuda por favor, gracias!!!

```
public function index(){

    require("third_party/PhpWord/PhpWord.php");
    require("third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php");

    try {
        $phpWord = new PhpWord();
        $section = $phpWord->addSection();
        $section->addText('Hello World');
        $objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
        header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='myFile.docx'");
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: me sale este error Message: Class 'PhpWord' not found

Comment: Probablemente tengas mal el path de la clase. De última podés usar `__DIR__` para usarlo como referencia al archivo en el que estás. `require(__DIR__ . "third_party/etc/clase.php")`.